# filling a new column based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, criteria

Suppose that I have a dataset with three categorical columns: df.type1  df.type2  df.type3 and I want to create a new column [df.new] that it takes:

```
df.new = df.type1 if df.type1 is true and the remaining are false
df.new = df.type2 if df.type2 is true and the remaining are false
df.new = df.type3 if df.type3 is true and the remaining are false
```

What is the best approach? I am quite confused by np.where() - too long and too script intense

Example:

```
City    dt.t1   dt.t2   dt.t3
NY       US Non    EU   Non Asia
Rome     Non US    EU   Non Asia
SF       US Non    EU   Non Asia
HK       Non US    Non EU   Asia
```

my final result would be:

```
City  dt.new
NY    US
Rome  EU
SF    US
HK    Asia
```

Comment: Is possible add small data sample?

Comment: Thank you for data, what is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.set_index('City')
df['dt.new'] = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+'))).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Alternative solution with select columns for check values:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='^dt\.').columns
#or use list of columns names
#cols = ['dt.t1','dt.t2','dt.t3']
df['dt.new'] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+'))).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

---

```
print (df)
       dt.t1   dt.t2     dt.t3 dt.new
City                                 
NY        US  Non EU  Non Asia     US
Rome  Non US      EU  Non Asia     EU
SF        US  Non EU  Non Asia     US
HK    Non US  Non EU      Asia   Asia
```

**Detail**:

First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `City` column and then check for `Non` string with one or more whitespaces:

```
df = df.set_index('City')

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+')))
      dt.t1  dt.t2  dt.t3
City                     
NY    False   True   True
Rome   True  False   True
SF    False   True   True
HK     True   True  False
```

Then replace matching values to `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print (df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+'))))
     dt.t1 dt.t2 dt.t3
City                  
NY      US   NaN   NaN
Rome   NaN    EU   NaN
SF      US   NaN   NaN
HK     NaN   NaN  Asia
```

Forward fill non missing values per rows:

```
print (df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+'))).ffill(axis=1))
     dt.t1 dt.t2 dt.t3
City                  
NY      US    US    US
Rome   NaN    EU    EU
SF      US    US    US
HK     NaN   NaN  Asia
```

And last select last column:

```
print (df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Non\s+'))).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
City
NY        US
Rome      EU
SF        US
HK      Asia
Name: dt.t3, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

```
m1 = df['dt.t1'] == 'US'
m2 = df['dt.t2'] == 'EU'
m3 = df['dt.t3'] == 'Asia'

df['dt.new'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['US','EU','Asia'], default=None)
```

Or:

```
df['dt.new'] = np.where(m1, 'US',
               np.where(m2, 'EU',
               np.where(m3, 'Asia', None)))
```

---

```
print (df)
   City   dt.t1   dt.t2     dt.t3 dt.new
0    NY      US  Non EU  Non Asia     US
1  Rome  Non US      EU  Non Asia     EU
2    SF      US  Non EU  Non Asia     US
3    HK  Non US  Non EU      Asia   Asia
```

Comment: thanks, in my specific case, df.t1 df.t2 dt.3 are objects: df.t1 = ['EU', 'Non EU'], df.t2 = ['US', 'Non US'] df.t3 = [['Asia', 'Non Asia'], how to make it work in this case?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - What are conditions?

Comment: thanks so much, but I find this even more script than np.where().. how would yopu approach it with np.where()? it seems I cannot get it right

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - Sure, momment.